# How to store a selected dropdown value to a php variable without submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have dropdown. When I select any value and click on confirm, Below it should print the selected value and also the selected value should be shown in the dropdown. How can I achieve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Links related to dropdown-->
    <link href="http://localhost/performance/Test/css/fselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://localhost/performance/Test/js/fSelect.js"></script>

     <script>
    (function($) {
        $(function() { 
            $('#project_name').fSelect();
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $projects = array('Trial','Test','Birds','Animals');
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div><center><b>This test will be created in the selected project:</b></center></div><br>
        <div class="create_test">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div style="margin-left:2cm;">
                    <select  name="project_name" id="project_name" >
                        <?php
                            for($i=0; $i<count($projects); $i++) {
                                echo "<option value='".$projects[$i]."'>".$projects[$i]."</option>";    
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" style="margin-left:3.5cm; width:140px;" name="submit"  id="comfirm" class="btn btn-success" value="Confirm" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to look into `:selected`

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this?

Comment: You need to look into `localStorage`.

Comment: In the title you ask "how to store the selected value to a php variable without submitting", which (due to the PHP reference) implies you want to send the selected value to the server without a postback, The answer to that is to use AJAX. But then in the question itself you say you simply say "When I select any value and click on confirm, Below it should print the selected value"...which implies you just want to handle the click on confirm using JS and display the selected value somewhere on the page. Which scenario do you actually want? Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: Yeah I have tried solving @Patrick

Comment: @Aadhya Then show the code that you tried, and explain the result and how it differs from what you want, along with what debugging you have done.

Comment: Also kind of need to see the code in the fSelect.js file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
/** Store selected in a varaible in php */
$selected = 'trial';// Suppose get the value from db here
                            for($i=0; $i<count($projects); $i++) {
                                echo "<option value='".$projects[$i]."' selected='".$project[$i] == $selected."'>".$projects[$i]."</option>";    
                            }
                        ?>
```

So adding the selected='true' will be used as value for the select tag